# Symfony 6 CollectionType on edit not saving new entry

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I'm encountering a rather frustrating issue that I've been trying to resolve for the past 12 hours.

I have a User entity that includes collections of Formations and Experiences. For the sake of this example, let's focus on the Formations. I've created the FormType for the User entity, named "CandidatType.php," which includes a field for the CollectionType of the Formation class. The relationship between these two is a OneToMany, meaning that each Formation can only belong to one User. I've diligently followed the documentation, including all the necessary JavaScript, and everything appears to be working as expected. I can add or remove sub-forms for Formations within the Candidat edit form, and even delete them.

However, when I try to submit the form with one or more Formation sub-forms, nothing happens. There are no errors, and no data is being saved to the database. It's as if the submission has no effect whatsoever.

here is my github projet : https://github.com/euroR67/talentblend ,  you have every needed file in there is needed to see more :

CandidatType.php :

```
            ->add('formations', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => FormationType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
            ])
            ->add('experiences', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ExperienceType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
            ])
```

CandidatController :

```
#[Route('/candidat/{id}/edit', name: 'app_candidat_edit')]
    public function edit(Request $request, User $user, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, SluggerInterface $slugger): Response
    {
        $originalFormations = new ArrayCollection();

        // Créez un tableau contenant les formations actuelles de l'utilisateur
        foreach ($user->getFormations() as $formation) {
            $originalFormations->add($formation);
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(CandidatType::class, $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // Si le formulaire est soumis et valide
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_candidat_edit', ['id' => $user->getId()]);
        }
        
        // Si le formulaire n'est pas soumis, on affiche le formulaire
        return $this->render('candidat/profil.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

the twig view :

```
{% extends 'dashboard.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Profil{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="wrapper">

    <h2>Paramètres du profil</h2>

    <ul class="tab">
        <li class="active">Votre profil</li>
        <li>Formation</li>
        <li>Expérience</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="section-wrapper">

        <div class="profil">
            <h3>Vos informations</h3>

            {{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.photo) }}
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        {# Si l'utilisateur a déjà une photo de profil, on l'affiche #}
                        {% if app.user.photo %}
                            <img src="{{ asset('pdp/' ~ app.user.photo) }}" alt="avatar">
                            <label for="deletePhoto">Supprimer la photo</label>
                            {{ form_row(form.deletePhoto) }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.cv) }}
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        {# Si l'utilisateur a déjà un CV, on l'affiche #}
                        {% if app.user.cv %}
                            <a href="{{ asset('cv/' ~ app.user.cv) }}" target="_blank">Voir le CV</a>
                            <label for="deleteCV">Supprimer le CV</label>
                            {{ form_row(form.deleteCV) }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.nom) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.prenom) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.metiers) }}
                </div>
            
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.description) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.niveau) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.langues) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.villes) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_row(form.active) }}
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        <div class="formation" style="display: none;">

            <h3>Formations</h3>

            <div id="formations" 
            data-prototype="{{ include("candidat/_formation.html.twig", {form: form.formations.vars.prototype})|e("html_attr") }}" 
            data-index="{{ form.formations|length > 0 ? form.formations|last.vars.name + 1 : 0}}">

                {% for formation in form.formations %}
                    <div class="col-4">
                        {{ include("candidat/_formation.html.twig", {form: formation}) }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
            {# {{ form_row(form.formations) }} #}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-new" data-collection="#formations" id="new-formation">New Formation</button>

        </div>
        {{ form_errors(form.formations) }}
        <div class="experience" style="display: none;">

            <h3>Expériences</h3>

            <div id="experiences" 
            data-prototype="{{ include("candidat/_experience.html.twig", {form: form.experiences.vars.prototype})|e("html_attr") }}" 
            data-index="{{ form.experiences|length > 0 ? form.experiences|last.vars.name + 1 : 0}}">

                {% for experience in form.experiences %}
                    <div class="col-4">
                        {{ include("candidat/_experience.html.twig", {form: experience}) }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
            {# {{ form_row(form.experiences) }} #}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-new" data-collection="#experiences" id="new-experience">New Experience</button>

        </div>
        {{ form_errors(form.experiences) }}
    </div>
    <button>Annuler</button>
    <button type="submit">Appliquer</button>
    {{ form_end(form, {render_rest: false}) }}

    <script>

        const newItem = (e) => {
            // On récupère l'id du bouton btn-new qui est cliqué 
            const collectionHolder = document.querySelector(e.currentTarget.dataset.collection);

            const item = document.createElement('div');
            item.classList.add('col-4');
            item.innerHTML = collectionHolder
            .dataset
            .prototype
            .replace(
                /__name__/g, 
                collectionHolder.dataset.index
            );
            item.querySelector(".btn-remove").addEventListener('click', () => item.remove());

            collectionHolder.appendChild(item);

            collectionHolder.dataset.index++;

            
        };
 
        document
        .querySelectorAll('.btn-remove')
        .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.currentTarget.closest('.col-4').remove()));

        document
        .querySelectorAll('.btn-new')
        .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', newItem));

    </script>
    
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Formation included file twig

```
{{ form_row(form.titre) }}
{{ form_row(form.qualification)}}
{{ form_row(form.dateDebut) }}
{{ form_row(form.dateFin) }}
{{ form_row(form.description) }}
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

I've exhausted all my options and I'm completely out of ideas. I've spent hours watching two full 2-hour videos, delved into the entire documentation about CollectionType, and tried many other things, but I'm still unable to understand why the new entries aren't being persisted and flushed.

This post might be getting quite lengthy, so I've decided not to include the code for the Entity. Instead, I've provided the GitHub project link so you can take a look for yourself.

I've also made sure to use "cascade persist" wherever it's required in my code.

EDIT / PROBLEM SOLVED BY :

Moving out the form_start from the divs...

[image]

Comment: You have one FormType with two collections, I think you must begin by rename each prototype pattern: first collection: 'prototype_name' => '___ formationsproto ___ , and second collection 'prototype_name' => '___ experiencesproto ___' . I don't see yours prototypes macros definition.